Specifing between Json web tokens and express session for authentication
Between JSON Web Tokens and express session, which is the best?
I'm just getting started with node.js.
This is my method for creating a new user, so should I use express session or JWT to save the session?
const Auth = require('../models/AuthModel');

const create_user = async (req, res) => {
    const { username, email, password, confirmPassword, country } = req.body;

    // Validate required fields
    if (!username || !email || !password || !confirmPassword || !country) {
        return res.status(400).send('All fields are required');
    }

    // Check if password and confirm password match
    if (password !== confirmPassword) {
        return res.status(400).send('Passwords do not match');
    }

    // Check email format
    const emailRegex = /^[^\s@]+@[^\s@]+\.[^\s@]+$/;
    if (!emailRegex.test(email)) {
        return res.status(400).send('Invalid email format');
    }

    try {
        const auth = new Auth({ username, email, password, country });
        await auth.save();
        res.redirect('/index');
    } catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
        res.status(500).send('Error creating user');
    }
};

module.exports = {
    create_user,
};


It is depend upon what kind of application your building?If it is Monolithic then go with express session and if it is microservice then use passport or jwt.

There is no best, but you should absolutely start with a simple session until you're running into limitations. Most people will not. Sessions are easier to deal with and harder to fuck up.
